# Wondering what the word "struck" in this context of news really mean

Tags: word-meaning

Here is the paragraph in concern:

> *After cautiously welcoming the deal **struck** on Thursday, the White House has now stepped up pressure on Russia to use its influence over separatists occupying the buildings in nine cities and towns in eastern Ukraine.*

I think it is passive, but I cannot figure out what does it mean. Checking dictionary did not help me at all. Could you also provide me some more examples using the word "struck" to mean similar things.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct (about it having a sense of the passive).

The phrase ***"the deal struck on Thursday"*** is a noun phrase, meaning "the deal that was struck on Thursday". The word *struck* here is a "past participle" used after a noun to define or identify the noun.

The phrase "strike a deal" is commonly used in the context of negotiation and making deals.

According to Macmillan Dictionary,

> **[strike](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/strike)**
>   12 [transitive] to make something such as a deal or an agreement by which both sides get an advantage or a benefit
>   **strike a deal/bargain:** *These questions must be answered before a deal can be struck.*